# Convert a list of vertex sequences to table in R

Tags: r, list, igraph

I am using the function the `adjacent_vertices()` from `igraph` package. It returns a list of vertex sequences.

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_graph("Zachary")
mylist <- adjacent_vertices(g, c(1,2), mode="out")

#    [[1]]
    + 16/34 vertices, from 5feb73a:
     [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 11 12 13 14 18 20 22 32

#    [[2]]
    + 9/34 vertices, from 5feb73a:
    [1]  1  3  4  8 14 18 20 22 31
```

I need to find a short presentation of the result, like this:

```
V Count
[1] 16
[2] 9
```

Here **V** is the vertex name and **Count** is out-degree.

I have tried to use:

```
degree(g)[1]
    # 16
degree(g)[2]     
    # 9
```

**Question.** Is it possible to convert the list of list to table or is exist a built-in function in the `igraph` package?

**Edit.** The number of vertexes in the original graph more than 100.

Comment: Can't you use the `v` argument of `degree`? Like `v <- c(1, 34)`; `setNames(degree(g, v), v)` or `data.frame(v = v, deg = degree(g, v))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is that you have an unamed graph (you can see that using `V(g)$name` which returns `NULL`). In this case, you can use the vertices `id` instead of `name`.

To get vertices `id`, you have to use `V(g)`. You can convert this `igraph.vs` object as a vector using `as.vector(V(g))`. This will provide a vector containing all the vertices `id`.

Then you can combine `as.vector(V(g))` and the `degree()` function to get your table (`data.frame`) using:

```
data.frame(V = as.vector(V(g)),
           Count = degree(g, v = V(g), mode = "out"))
# outupt
    V Count
1   1    16
2   2     9
3   3    10
4   4     6
5   5     3
6   6     4
7   7     4
8   8     4
9   9     5
10 10     2
11 11     3
12 12     1
13 13     2
14 14     5
15 15     2
16 16     2
17 17     2
18 18     2
19 19     2
20 20     3
21 21     2
22 22     2
23 23     2
24 24     5
25 25     3
26 26     3
27 27     2
28 28     4
29 29     3
30 30     4
31 31     4
32 32     6
33 33    12
34 34    17
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be helpful for you. First, get a list vertex of adjacent vertices.

```
vlist=V(g)$name
vercount=adjacent_vertices(g, vlist, mode="out")
```

Now make two vectors for vertex names and vertex degree.

```
vertexname=vector(`)
vertexcount=vector()
```

Then find the count of adjacent vertices.

```
for(i in 1:length(vlist))
{
  vertexname[i]=vlist[i]
  vertexcount[i]=length(vercount[[i]])
}
df=data.frame(vertexname,vertexcount)
df
```

This will give you complete list of vertices and their degree.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. But how to be in common case when the vertex's number is big?

Comment: please describe, how many number of vertices are ? and mentiion the dataset name.

Comment: the number of vertices is greater than 100.